# Shortest distance to a straight line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Find the coordinates of the point on the ellipse $4x^{2}+y^{2}=4$, which is closest to the straight line $x+y=10$. I could solve it by using Lagrange Multiplier. Is there any way to solve it graphically?

Thank you.

Comment: Tried projection?

Comment: let $P_1(x_1;y_1)$ a point on the ellipse and $P_2(x_2;y_2)$ a point on the straight line. How is the distance?

Comment: The Lagrange Multiplier method has a nice graphical interpretation...

Comment: The tangent will be parallel to $x+y=10$

Comment: take a tangent parallel to $x+y=10$ that is $x+y=a$ now find $a$ using condition for tangency and hence find point of contact

Answer (score 2):

The Lagrange multiplier method has a nice graphical interpretation.

We look for points where the normals are parallel.

The normal to the line is $(1,1)^T$.

The normal to the ellipse at $(x,y)$ is given by $(8x,2x)^T$.

Hence we look for points (x,y) lying on the ellipse satisfying $(8x,2x)^T= \lambda (1,1)^T$.

This gives ${5 \over 16} \lambda^2 = 4$, or
$\lambda = \pm \sqrt{64 \over 5}$, from which we can get the $(x,y)$ values.

**Alternative**:

Consider the family of parallel lines $L_t$ given by $x+y=t$ and find the $t$ for
which the intersection of the ellipse and the line $L_t$
results in exactly one point.

Substituting $y=t=x$ into the equation for the ellipse gives
$4x^2+(t-x)^2 =4$ and solving for $x$ gives
$x = { t \pm 2 \sqrt{5-t^2} \over 5} $. Hence we must have
$t = \pm \sqrt{5}$. Substituting gives $x$ and then $y = t-x$.

Comment: Equivalently, we’re looking for points on the ellipse at which the tangent is parallel to the given line. These tangents can be constructed with compass and straightedge. http://www.practicalstudent.com/subjects/tg/planefigures/ellangtang.shtml shows a way to do this.

Comment: No, we just want the normals of the line intersect the ellipse and minimize the distance line to intersection point. No normal or tangent condition on the point on the ellipse.

Comment: @mvw That minimal distance will in fact occur at a point at which the normal to the ellipse is parallel to the normal to the given line (eqv. the tangent is parallel to the line).

Comment: @amd What is the normal of an ellipse? A vector orthogonal to the tangential vector at the intersection point on the ellipse? A tangential vector is not just a line intersecting the ellipse at one point but derived from the geometry of the ellipse curve. I would think that in general this is not the case.

Comment: My line of thought is that the ellipse might be a rotated one, then all the tangential vectors get rotated as well and can have no dependency to the orientation of the line. Maybe we mean something else by tangent etc.

Comment: @mvw Backing up a bit (I shouldn’t do this when I’m tired and ill). The parallels to the line are loci of constant distance from the line. Geometrically, the nearest point of the ellipse is one for which the parallel through that point lies between the given line and the rest of the ellipse. Clearly, this parallel may only intersect the ellipse at a single point, so this is equivalent to saying that the tangent to the ellipse at that point is parallel to the given line. The relationship between the normals follows from orthogonality. This is independent of the coordinate system.

Comment: @mwv The Lagrange multiplier method agrees nicely with the geometrical view. The level curves of the distance-to-line function are the parallels to the given line, so its gradient is everywhere normal to the line. The ellipse is a level curve of $4x^2+y^2$, so the gradient of that function is normal to the ellipse. The Lagrange multiplier method tells us to look for points at which these two gradients are parallel, i.e., where the normal to the ellipse is also normal to the given line. I’d be happy to continue this discussion in chat if you’d like. It’s helping me to sharpen my explanations.

Answer (score 1):

similar to [Max perpendicular distance between line and parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593258/11206):
find the tangent parallel to the line.

[image]

a way to construct the solution using compass and ruler can be found [here](http://www.practicalstudent.com/subjects/tg/planefigures/ellangtang.shtml)

Comment: That would be the same as finding parallel normals.

Comment: @copper: If it is the same why did you add this "Alternative" paragraph to your post afterwards?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I added an unrelated alternative answer which has nothing to do with any other answer. It has a nice geometric interpretation which is what the OP was looking for. Your answer is essentially Lagrange multipliers, which is what my first answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

When $A,B$ are not both zero, the distance from a point $(u,v)$ to the line $A x +B y+C=0$ is $|A u+B v+C|/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}.\;$ For a point $(u,v)$ on the ellipse $4 x^2+y^2=4,\;$ let $u=\cos t$ and $v=2\sin t.$ The distance from $(\cos t, 2\sin t)$ to the line $x+y-10=0$ is $ \;|\cos t+2\sin t -10|/\sqrt 2.\;$  The largest value of $(\cos t+2\sin t)$ is $\sqrt 5,$ which is attained only when $\cos t=1/\sqrt 5$ and $\sin t=2/\sqrt 5.$ So the shortest distance from the ellipse to the line is $(10-\sqrt 5)/\sqrt 2\;$ which occurs only when $(u,v)=(\cos t,2\sin t)=(1/\sqrt 5,\;4/\sqrt 5).$

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to solve it graphically?

I measured it in GeoGebra. It is about $(0.39,1.84)^t$.

[image: distance ellipse to line]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63HUa.png))

**Geometrical Solution:**

The line $a$ was
$$
(x, y)^T \cdot (1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})^T = 10/\sqrt{2}
$$
A normal line $b$ to it, with intersection $(x,y)^T$ on $a$ is
$$
(x,y)^T + t (1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}) \quad (t \in \mathbb{R})
$$
After a distance $d$ line $b$ intersects the ellipse at $(u,v)^T$
$$
4 = 4u^2+v^2 \Rightarrow \\
v = 2 \sqrt{1-u^2} 
$$
where we picked the positive root for the intersection point on the ellipse closer to the line $a$. We have
$$
(x, y) - d (1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}) = (u, v)
$$
We must have
$$
(u + d/\sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{1-u^2}+d/\sqrt{2}) = (u + d/\sqrt{2}, 10-u-d/\sqrt{2})
$$
where the equation for the $y$-components gives the distance in terms of $u$:
$$
2\sqrt{1-u^2}+d/\sqrt{2} = 10-u-d/\sqrt{2} \iff \\
d = \frac{10-u-2 \sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
We want to minimize $d$ in terms of $u$ and look at the derivative
$$
d' = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2} \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$
For a local extrema this must vanish:
$$
\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \\
u = 1/\sqrt{5} \Rightarrow \\
v = 4/\sqrt{5}
$$
Here the result is $(u,v) = (0.447, 1.789)$.

**Comparison:**

The measurement had an error of $13\%$ for $u$ and $3\%$ for $v$.
The calculated minimal distance is $5.49$, thus the same as the measured one.

Comment: How did you determine that this was in fact the nearest point to the line?

Comment: I moved the normal, which moves the intersection points, and watched the calculated distance. Of course it has some error.

Comment: That doesn’t really strike me as a “solution” to the problem.

Comment: Requested was a graphical solution.

Comment: Well, we definitely have different interpretations of what the OP wanted. To me, that meant a rigorous geometrical construction.